# PrintImage causing corrupt memory error

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, memory-corruption

I am having a problem using the `PrintImage` function of the ActivePDF C# library. When I use it to try to place a .gif image on the PDF I receive this error message:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I am able to use the `PrintJPEG` and `PrintTIFF` image functions without any problem.  Has anyone run into this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Is that image coming from a picturebox or similar control? If that's the case, then that control has a lock on that image (I ran into the same situation while trying to serialize an object that contained an image from an inkpicture control). You would need to copy the image before placing it in your pdf document.

Comment: The picture is uploaded via a FileUpload control on a web form. I am able to upload jpg/tif and use them, just not anything that uses the generic PrintImage.

Comment: If that's the case, then sorry, I'm not really sure what the problem could be. It still sounds like something has a lock on the image but I wouldn't know where to go from here.